# AWS EMR Spark: Error writing to S3 - IllegalArgumentException - Cannot create a path from an empty string

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have been trying to fix this for a long time now ... no idea why I get this? FYI, I'm running Spark on a cluster on AWS EMR Cluster. I debugged and clearly see the destination path provided ... something like `s3://my-bucket-name/`. The spark job creates orc files and writes them after creating a partition like so: `date=2017-06-10`. Any ideas?

```
17/07/08 22:48:31 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.suffix(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.deleteMatchingPartitions(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:82)
```

code that writes orc:

```
dataframe.write
   .partitionBy(partition)
   .option("compression", ZLIB.toString)
   .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
   .orc(destination)
```

Comment: Is there any chance there is an empty partitions?

Comment: The orc files are first written to a `_temporary` directory, and then later moved to the main directory. Not sure how that scenario would crop up!

Comment: Post the code it might help understanding the problem

Comment: Updated question with the code that writes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen a similar problem when writing parquet files to S3. The problem is the `SaveMode.Overwrite`. This mode doesn't seem to work correctly in combination with S3. Try to delete all the data in your S3 bucket `my-bucket-name` before writing into it. Then your code should run successfully.

To delete all files from your bucket `my-bucket-name` you can use the following pyspark code:

```
# see https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-overwrite-the-output-directory-when-using-PySpark
URI = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

# see http://crazyslate.com/how-to-rename-hadoop-files-using-wildcards-while-patterns/
fs = FileSystem.get(URI("s3a://my-bucket-name"), sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
file_status = fs.globStatus(Path("/*"))
for status in file_status:
    fs.delete(status.getPath(), True)
```