# AWS glue parquet conversion in to s3

Tags: etl, aws-glue

We are using aws glue etl jobs to convert the s3 Json or CSV to parquet format and the result we are saving in nnew s3 .
This job is running periodically.
We are facing an issue,for example if we have 10json files each time it runs it is creating new 10parquet files so it becomes 10 20 30 40....and so on we only want to see 10 files .
Is there any way we can override existing parquet files .We are using glue generated Python script only.
Can we convert only the updated files or can we overdue all files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("/output/folder/path") works if you want to overwrite a parquet file using python.

Comment: Hi Kishore Thanks for the response tried the same .Validating our results

Comment: Hi Kishore one more issue ..if our columns are having space then this method is causing issue,we tried alias still the same.

Comment: I tried the suggested code that uses the overwrite mode with my ETL job (that converts csv from s3 to parquet in another s3, but it seems the job doesn't work and throws an exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string

Later on I found a blog post about the exact same issue saying that overwrite mode with s3 and parquet doesn't work at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991550/aws-emr-spark-error-writing-to-s3-illegalargumentexception-cannot-create-a

Comment: UPDATE: the overwrite mode works fine if you include at least one top level folder in your s3 path.