# EMR to S3 file writing gives me error java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am running a pyspark application from EMR cluster. I have two buckets -an input data bucket *user-data-input* and an o/p data bucket to store the script results *movie-stats*. My code for writing to the output bucket

```
final_df = ratings.join(movie_title, 'movieId', 'left') \
    .select('movieId', 'title', 'release_year', 'avg_rating', 'ratings_count', 'distinct_viewers') \
    .coalesce(1)
final_df.write.csv('s3://movie-stats', header=True, mode='overwrite')
```

My bucket policy for *movie-stats* is below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1606478144619",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1606478053538",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::movie-stats/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::movie-stats"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My script can read data from the S3 bucket and run the analysis, but throws error when trying to writing to S3 as

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: s3://movie-stats.spark-staging-f2e2ecd7-5c42-483a-888c-6a6295b76c0d
```

I do not understand this error and did not find much from google to understand how the S3 path should be mentioned for outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem with this code. The spark app needs the output folder that does not exist. So the output bucket **s3://movie-stats** already exists. So the solution is to add a bucket path s3://movie-stats/output.

Secondly, writing to S3 with file overwrite has issues. So the final code fix is

```
final_df.write.csv('s3://movie-stats/output', header=True)
```

If running the script again then the folder needs to be deleted before the data can be load again. Refer to this [AWS EMR Spark: Error writing to S3 - IllegalArgumentException - Cannot create a path from an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991550/aws-emr-spark-error-writing-to-s3-illegalargumentexception-cannot-create-a) for python code to delete the files.

Answer (score 1):

Ypu've already worked it out, but root directories are special, they never go away.

Applications written for filesystems never expect to use / as their output, so don't work so well with it as the root for object store output.